# Why is Cybertron larger than earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, transformers-prime

In the Transformers Prime episode *Deadlock,* the Deceptions constructed a new Omega Lock with the intention of cyberforming the earth, which we know has Unicron for its core. After the Autobots obtained it, Ratchet told Optimus that it might not work for restarting Cybertron, which has Primus for its core, because the Cybertron is so much larger than earth. Since both planets contain the bodies of assumedly equal beings of creation and destruction, why was Cybertron larger? In One shall Rise, Optimus theorized that the reason no one noticed Unicron within our planet was the fact that debris from space slowly gathered around his slumbering form, gradually forming the planet we live on. This, however, would lead us to the conclusion that earth should be larger than Cybertron, not the other way around.

Why is Cybertron larger than earth? Is there significantly more matter in Cybertron than what was originally a part of Primus? Alternatively, if Unicron was smaller than Primus, can anyone explain why? Was there ever a definitive statement of proportional size, or in-cannon evidence of battles (with the 13 or otherwise) where he lost mass?

Also, please note that this question is about transformers-prime, anyone who points out Gen-1 size inconsistencies without tying them to this continuity will not be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: As stated in the episode [***One Shall Rise, Part 1***](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/One_Shall_Rise,_Part_1) of Prime, Primus merged with the existing planet Cybertron after he and the thirteen defeated Unicron. The size of Earth and size of Cybertron are mutually exclusive. From what I remember, Primus created Cybertron on purpose, Earth was a coincidence of Unicron floating in space.

---

Unicron is typically depicted as the "that's not a moon" to Primus' planet size. Cybertron has always been depicted as larger than Earth.

They never provide an explanation of how much mass was around Unicron as the planet formed, but that would have more to do with how much other planet forming mass was in the areas around the solar system and the stars in that system and etc (celestial gravitational forces are complicated). On the other hand, Cybertron was both built, and living, mechanical life, while the Earth was assumed to be inert material that life happen to start on the face of.

But Primus is the life bringer. It's only natural for the Force of creation to be bigger than the Force of destruction. Look at humans vs transformers for size comparison. And as is shown often, size has nothing to do with strength.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I had forgotten that Cybertron was a pre-existing planet, which makes sense since A) the thirteen existed with Primus (a bit hard to do if their planet doesn’t exist), and B) many of the structures on the surface seem to exist on top of him, not as a part of him. I am not certain if your last point holds weight, but in all I am very satisfied with this answer. Accepted and +1.